# Introduction to relativity books

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, relativity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting started general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363/getting-started-general-relativity)

I am an engineer who loves to read science fiction books especially when there's more science than fiction but usually I see that I lack the knowledge behind many of the relativity concepts in the novels. I've always felt curiosity in relativity so I decided that it was the time to buy an introductory book. I went to amazon and checked that there are dozens of "Introduction to general relativity" books in there.
So here's my question: What book would you recommend to someone not matematician nor physicist but with (some) mathematical background as an introduction to relativity?

Comment: I would suggest [A Most Incomprehensible Thing: Notes Towards a Very Gentle Introduction to the Mathematics of Relativity](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Most-Incomprehensible-Thing-Introduction-Mathematics/dp/0957389450)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question depends largely on various factors, therefore there is no point to list all books I know of. A couple books, however, stand out for an "informed" laymen. One by George Ellis and Ruth Williams, and another by Bob Geroch.

[http://www.amazon.com/Flat-Curved-Space-Times-George-Ellis/dp/0198506562/ref=ntt_at_ep_dpt_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198506562)

[http://www.amazon.com/General-Relativity-B-Robert-Geroch/dp/0226288641/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1316698577&sr=1-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0226288641)

Both are elementary, but very lucid and didn't sacrifice sophistication of physical principles behind. I would, indeed, recommend both to any serious students of relativity.

Another good source [will be better soon] is relativity site of ComPadre, The spacetime Emporium.

http://www.compadre.org/relativity/

You may find many online sources there.

Answer (score 0):

There is an awesome introduction to relativity, which puts the emphasis on understanding (including different paradoxes) while reducing the mathematical tools only to the necessary ones:

- [Andrzej Dragan](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Edragan/), [Niezwykle szczególna teoria względności](http://www.fuw.edu.pl/%7Edragan/Fizyka/Nstw.pdf) (in Polish, *Exceptionally special relativity*)

(If, for some reason, you do not understand Polish I recommend to keep bugging the author to translate it :).)

**EDIT**: Now it is in English, published Dec 2021: [Unusually Special Relativity](https://doi.org/10.1142/q0319)!