# Where to read about Minkowski space

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations

When I learned Special Relativity, it was taught in terms of basic linear algebra, without any mention of the Minkowski space, proper time as integration on the metric, etc.

However, when I am trying to learn General Relativity from several books (Wald, Carroll, Weinberg), it seems they all assume I am already familiar with SR and Minkowski space, and only briefly review it.

So, I'm afraid I'll be missing some material here.

What is a good source for SR from a Riemannian geometry point of view?

Comment: Since Minkowski space is flat, there isn't a lot of geometry to be done. In any case, a valuable resource is the 'Gravitation' book by Misner-Thorne-Wheeler.

Comment: The answers to this questions (v1) is likely to be duplicates of e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451 See also e.g. http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Administrivia/rel_booklist.html

Answer (score 0):

For semi-Riemannian geometry in general (including some discussion of flat space) it's hard to beat *[Semi-Riemannian Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125267401)* by O'Neill.

I assume you've already looked at the Wiki pages for Minkowski space, but also try [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold).

Lastly, Hartle's *[Gravity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805386629)* has a great introduction to relativity in Minkowski space in the first few chapters.