# Book recommendation for self study of General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I am a second year Chemical Engineering student. However out of interest I wish to learn General theory of relativity. Can anyone please suggest some books for learning this subject?

Comment: I really liked General Relativity by Hobson, Efstathiou and Lasenby for having a very physical (rather than mathematical) approach (which I recommend because you don't seem to come from a mathematical background)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting started self-studying general relativity](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/)