# Books on black hole slicing

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations

I'm starting work on a summer project at my university soon, based in General Relativity. In particular, my project is focused on slicing of black holes. The problem, however, I've never taken a General Relativity course (I've taken Differential Geometry, though), and I'm having trouble finding something to read that gives a "gentle" introduction to black hole slicings.

If you can recommend anything at all that I should read to help my understanding, I would be truly grateful.

Comment: I don't think you have much of a choice but to learn GR; the good news is that if you know differential geometry this shouldn't be too hard. There's already a question on book recommendations with some good answers.

Comment: Related possible duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/217207/book-recommendation-for-self-study-of-general-relativity.   Or just use the search box to the top right to search "general relativity books"

Comment: A lot of the books listed I've looked through, and can't find anything that deals with slicing, though. For an introductory book it's easy to find but none of them deal with slicing (that I could see anyways).

Comment: Poisson, or any book on numerical relativity (especially https://www.amazon.ca/Numerical-Relativity-Einsteins-Equations-Computer/dp/052151407X)

Answer (score 1):

Learning GR for beginners...well, there's a [thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/363/getting-started-self-studying-general-relativity) on that topic.

As far as space-like hypersurfaces foliating spacetime ("slicing spacetime"), a good *first* book would be Poisson's *A Relativist's Toolkit*, specifically chapter 1 (to learn the notation and review any background concepts) and chapter 3 (to learn the mathematics of hypersurfaces).

Your research mentor should be a good resource and provide references, though. I'm sure asking him or her "Hey, I don't have a good background on hypersurfaces, what's a good reference?" is better than asking the internet...

Comment: He's away for a week and a half right now and unreachable, which is why I asked. Thanks for your input, though.