# Textbook to understand special/general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I want to understand special and/or general relativity in details, including computations, space/time curvature, etc. What textbook do you recommend?

Comment: We would need to know your background at very least. There is a [community book recommendation post here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12175/book-recommendations) too that might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/)