# General treatment of connections and covariant derivatives

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, curvature, education

Hi have been following an introductory course on quantum gravity and we are covering the basics of free quantum field theory in curved spaces.

I have been introduced to how spin connections play a role in the covariant derivatives of spinorial objects but only lightly.

The issue is that the course I followed in General Relativity had little to no focus on the actual differential geometry lying below the theory, I know how it works, but I would like to see a general and formally rigorous construction built on mathematical reasoning.

Can you suggest resources concerning the general geometrical meaning and role of connections?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard reference for connections is *Foundations of Differential Geometry* by Kobayashi & Nomizu (especially volume 1). This book contains only a treatment of connections on principal fibre bundles, which also include vector bundle connections as a special case.

The case of general Ehresmann connections are not treated here, however I'd argue that those are not super relevant to physics (some theories based on Finsler geometries use them, also Lagrangian mechanics can be reformulated in a way that the equations of motion are geodesics of a non-equivariant/non-linear connection on the tangent bundle, but these are kinda fringe cases).

A good discussion on connections (including the general case) can also be found in *Natural operations in differential geometry* by Kolár/Michor/Slovák ( [https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/kmsbookh.pdf) ).

A nice overview of the various different formalisms for connections and their relations to each other can be found in *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* by Spivak, especially volume 2 or 3 iirc (I don't remember exactly, and I am not in position right now to check).

*Gauge Theory and Variational Principles* by David Bleecker is a treatment of (classical) Yang-Mills theory and General Relativity via principal fibre bundles, so a good link between mathematics and physics can be found in this book.

*Natural and Gauge-Natural Formalism for Classical Field Theories* by Fatibene and Francaviglia is like the big brother of Bleecker, it is basically a book on the mathematical structure of classical field theory in general, thus it contains plenty of material on connections.

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I was looking for.