# Book recommendations to understand General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I just finished Multivariate calculus and I am wondering what sequence of books would allow me to work up to the mathematical knowledge needed to understand General Relativity and the corresponding field equations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/)

Comment: Paul Dirac's book "General Theory of Relativity"

Comment: Is Dirac's self contained?

Comment: There's a lot to learn, I suggest you to study these first: linear algebra, ordinary and some partial differential equations , tensor calculus, some differential geometry. Then you'll be set to go. Check Lewis Ryder Introduction to General Relativity. It also has nice chapters on differential geometry.

Comment: Thank you Monopole.