# Good introductory book about general relativity at undergraduate level?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I am looking for a good introductory book about general relativity at undergraduate level.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Books for general relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/)

Comment: @StenEdeback You might find the following link useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/ since you've now asked two book recommendation questions that have been closed as duplicates.