# What are the best books on general relativity for beginners?

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

so, I've tried several books. but many of them weren't designed to suit beginners such as myself. thus, being a beginner is completely related. in my case starting off with the motion, equations is the ideal start point {proof is ESSENTIAL}.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451 and links therein.

Comment: “Beginner” can mean many things. Do you know calculus? Do you know any classical mechanics? Do you know Special Relativity? Have you ever seen a tensor? Are you in high school, university, or graduate school?

Comment: You can see the equation of motion, and three derivations of it, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Mathematical_expression).

Comment: When I was about 16, I read the book by Lillian Lieber mentioned in some of the answers to the linked question. It was extremely influential on me.