# Where to start studying black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, resource-recommendations, education

I am working as an associate professor in mathematical economics and I am very interested in physics and especially in black holes. However, I do not know the prerequisites to understand these topics which use mathematics heavily .
I think I master most of the mathematical tools but I do not know where to start really? I have searched if somebody else asked a similar question but I did not find it.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363

Comment: the main relevant mathematical tool is differential geometry.

Comment: I assume you have some experience modeling systems that can be represented by a differential equation. If so, you may enjoy this recent article on photon trajectories around black holes: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-93595-w Also see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/45114/16685