# Learning general relativity, books on the math and an introductory guide for topic of general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, education

I am an aspiring physics major and want to self learn general relativity. I have formally taken multi variable/vector calculus and linear algebra and am currently taking tensor calculus. What are some introductory level books that go over the math needed, then over general relativity itself?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See my list:

[Sean M. Carroll - Spacetime and Geometry  An Introduction to General Relativity-Cambridge University Press (2019)][1]

[Carlip, Steven Jonathan - General relativity   a concise introduction-Oxford University Press (2019)][2]


  [1]: http://Sean%20M.%20Carroll%20-%20Spacetime%20and%20Geometry%20%20An%20Introduction%20to%20General%20Relativity-Cambridge%20University%20Press%20(2019)
  [2]: http://Carlip,%20Steven%20Jonathan%20-%20General%20relativity%20%20%20a%20concise%20introduction-Oxford%20University%20Press%20(2019)

Comment: For Undergraduate Lecture Notes in Physics

[Cosimo Bambi - Introduction to General Relativity-Springer Singapore (2018)][3]


  [3]: http://Cosimo%20Bambi%20-%20Introduction%20to%20General%20Relativity-Springer%20Singapore%20(2018)

Comment: Why is this closed? Such a list is a living document. I don't understand the moderators ,here on stackexchange.