# Is there a modern, worthy successor to Misner/Thorne/Wheeler "Gravitation"?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, resource-recommendations, education

About to purchase [Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's Gravitation](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691177793/gravitation) I wonder if there is a newer book covering the topic in similar depth and breath and all that which might also be “a pedagogic masterpiece,” as the cover text says.

While the reprint is from 2017, I couldn't find a hint that is was amended in some way, so I ask if there is a newer book with material or aspects or approaches to the topics which were not yet available in 1973?

$\tiny\text{Note: I am not a student at a University, just a curious old guy. :-)}$

EDIT: marking this as a duplicate seems somewhat appropriate. For posterity I'd like to note the publication dates:

- 2009 [A First Course in General Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521887054) by Bernard Schutz
- 2003 [Spacetime and Geometry: An Introduction to General Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805387323) by Sean Carroll
- 2002 [Gravity: An Introduction To General Relativity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805386629) by James Hartle, though a Cambridge University Press has "reissued" it 2021

And any kind of comparison to MTW as I kind-of ask above might be a bit too subjective.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It's great book, but I had Kip teaching the class, which definitely helped.

Comment: I had the misfortune to have to help a prof who had picked Hartle to teach students with it. While it is obviously a nicely written book, it is really so awkward in its presentation that there is little chance of students understanding GR from it.