# Looking for research papers in General relativity to read as a non-expert

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, research-level

I work in tech but I at some point I almost took a career path into theoretical physics. I changed my studies very late to data science and machine learning (my last masters year) and before that I was in physics and solid state physics.

I am looking for research papers that could be interesting to read for a non-expert like me. I am used to read physics research papers (mainly solid state physics and spintronics). I am looking for papers that do not have super heavy mathematical development.

An example would be the famous "More is different" from Anderson. It describes very well what I'm looking for although I'd prefer some mathematical perspective if applicable (but again not too much of it).

The idea is to read about topics like General relativity not from Wikipedia but from research papers that are either foundational or educative/pedagogic.

No books however I don't have time for them, I am not looking to study these subjects but rather acquire some insight and basic knowledge.

I am looking for now in papers in : general relativity

Comment: Reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.3555) might help you focus your question... or might begin to answer it.

Comment: Concerning GR books, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363/2451

Comment: Reading research papers is likely a waste of your time if you don’t even have textbook level knowledge…

Comment: @MattHanson I don't exactly agree, do you know "More is different" of Anderson? it's very accessible and very famous, and iirc there is not a single line of math

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks a lot! a bit dense for my but definitly a good starting point

Comment: @J.G. thanks a lot! is it about General relativity or Quantum gravity?

Comment: If you want a free online course, perhaps Leonard Susskind's [Theortical Minimum](https://theoreticalminimum.com/) courses would be of interest.

Comment: Since you've asked, the paper I suggested is about quantum gravity, so your recent focusing of the question might make it less relevant.

Comment: *it's very accessible and very famous, and iirc there is not a single line of math* OK, but most research papers are not like that.

Comment: @Ghoster yes I agree, I realize the kind of papers I am looking for are not exactly common but that is precisely the reason I am asking the question here. "More is different" is a bit extreme as an example though, I'm fine with mathematical developement (even if for example I have to go read a couple Wikipedia pages to understand concepts) but if it's really for experts in the fields and that you need to read many other papers to understand it then in that case yeah it would be a waste of time for me to read it

Comment: @J.G. alright thanks! it will be useful in the future for me so I'll keep it in mind

Comment: @BrahimKhalilAbid to be honest, reading about an area of theoretical physics as broad as GR without or with minimal math from purely physics (or math) research articles is not exactly possible, not even for someone who deals with these things on an applied level, let alone for a hobbyist. One of the main reasons is that "dumbing it down" doesn't help further the research itself. What you are looking for can only be found in popular science really.

Comment: @BrahimKhalilAbid however, if you are serious, the one source to learn the meat of it with minimal mathematics would be Einstein's own book, Relativity: The Special and the General Theory.